# Slide UITableView Off Screen?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uitableview, animation

I am trying to animate my UITableView sliding off the screen, I have tried this below without success:

```
-(void)slideTableViewOffScreen
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

    stageSelectionTable.frame = CGRectMake(stageSelectionTable.frame.origin.x - stageSelectionTable.frame.size.width, stageSelectionTable.frame.origin.y, stageSelectionTable.frame.size.height, stageSelectionTable.frame.size.width);

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Any ideas why it might not work, or what I need to do for this animation to work? When that code is called, nothing happens.

Comment: I just tried exactly your code (with a table view at 0 in X), and it is working fine on my side, except that it swaps the width and height of the table view. Can you try inverting the 2 last arguments of your CGRectMake? Also are you sure that your code gets called?

Comment: Code definitely gets called. Im thinking it could be because I have a Category class that sets the frame (as I need to have a narrow tableview). Any ideas how I could set the narrow width I need and have this work?

Comment: Ahh ok got it working but it does the same as you mentioned. it effects the size, not position. Thats bizarre, Im changing the x position not the size.

Comment: You are actually changing the size, as the 2 last arguments of CGRectMake are width and height and you are passing height, width. Out of curiosity, can you describe how you fixed your problem?

Comment: I've just temporarily removed the category class so I can get this animation working. However I haven't fixed the animation, it still changes size, not position. I understand what you say, but surely I am simply just telling it to keep the height and width and the tables current height and width?

Comment: With this line: stageSelectionTable.frame = CGRectMake(x-width, y, height, width), you are setting the final position and size of your view. UIView will interpolate between the current position and size and the final position and size, which will create the animation. However, in your case, you set the final position to current X - width, which hides the view if it is at 0 in X, but you are also setting its final size to (height,width) instead of (width,height), which swaps the sizes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this code works without any weirdness:

```
-(void)slideTableViewOffScreen
{
    CGRect newFrame = stageSelectionTable.frame;
    newFrame.origin.x -= 130;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

    stageSelectionTable.frame = newFrame;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```